# WCF cannot Serialization for Object (System.Byte[*] Type)

Tags: .net, wcf, marshalling, com-interop, datacontractserializer

All

Basically my WCF Service needs to connect to a DCOM Server and obtain a struct containing a "VARIANT" field and then pass it to my WCF Service client.

This is my WCF Data Contract for this Struct obtained from native DCOM Service

```
[DataContract]
[ComVisible(true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct tagProcReadAns
{
    [DataMember]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public object vItemValue;           //VARIANT: marshalled as object in C# 
    [DataMember]
    public ushort wQuality;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Error;}
```

since i expected this data contract can be registered as COM object and marshal back to C++ code again, that's why i have the [ComVisible] and [MarshalAs] part

Anyway, the vItemValue is the VARIANT object i obtained successfully from DCOM Server, (i have verified the content). However, when i encountered exceptions when i tried to pass it over the WCF.

I expected that the data contained in vItemValue VARIANT is of "byte array type" since i saw that the VARIANT.vt value is "VTUI1|VT_ARRAY", so i modify the DataContract as following

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(TypeOf(byte[])]  //new 
[ComVisible(true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct tagProcReadAns
{
    [DataMember]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public object vItemValue;           //VARIANT: marshalled as object in C# 
    [DataMember]
    public ushort wQuality;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Error;}
```

However, when i run the code again, i still ecountered exception, by adding the tracing, i have the following error messages

```
There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:aryAns. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Byte[*]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfunsignedByte:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

It seems that the data type is not byte[] but byte[*] ?? Is there anything wrong i have done?
and as the exception has suggested, i can use DataContractResolver to somehow solve this problem, can you suggest any solutions?

thank you

Comment: I figure out how to avoid the serialization issue mentioned above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out how to avoid the serialization issue mentioned above..

Basically what i did before is directly assign **vItemValue** i obtained from C++ code and then pass it over WCF service for serialization.

Follow @Marc Gravell suggestion, i have figure out that the data contract should be defined as following as **VARIANT** with  **VT_ARRAY|VT_*** type will by default marshalled to Managed code as Object with type System.Array (of byte) instead of System.Byte[] etc.

```
    [DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]    
[KnownType(typeof(byte))]
[KnownType(typeof(uint))]
[KnownType(typeof(UInt16))]
[KnownType(typeof(UInt64))]
[KnownType(typeof(ulong))]
[KnownType(typeof(System.Array))]  //here !!!!! for System.Byte[*]
[KnownType(typeof(byte[]))]
[ComVisible(true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct tagProcReadAns
{
    [DataMember]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public object vItemValue;           //VARIANT type has to be carefully marshalled 
    [DataMember]
    public ushort wQuality;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Error;         
}
```

In addtion, when passing the VARIANT object obtained from C++ code and pass over WCF boundary, i did a

```
System.Array result = System.Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), ((System.Array)ans[i].vItemValue).Length);
((System.Array)ans[i].vItemValue).CopyTo(result, 0);
```

instead of directly assign result to the ans[i].vItemValue

by doing this, i am able to pass the object accross the WCF boundary...

thanks Marc for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

`byte[*]` (or more specifically any `T[*]`) is a 1-dimensional array that is not explicitly a *vector* (a vector is a special category of array, zero-based, 1-dimensional). Referencing the type for such is pretty hard, since it doesn't directly exist in C# as a language (you need to use `Array` to talk to a non-vector 1-dimensional array).

My advice: introduce a dedicated DTO here. Trying to use an existing object model for serialization is often a good starting point, but when it gets tricky: use a DTO. I would add the following, and map to this manually **before** going anywhere near WCF:

```
[DataContract]
public class TagAnswer // or whatever this is
{
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Data {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public ushort Quality {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 ErrorCode {get;set;}
}
```

Your COM/struct is fine when talking to COM, but has no place whatsoever on a service boundary.

Comment: Related blog item, by the way: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/03/when-is-int-not-int.html

Comment: Hi, Marc: Thanks a lot for such a quick response. I have considered this approach you have suggested also. However i have the following concerns: (1) Since VARIANT in C++ can be any type from BSTR, int, byte to array, maybe it means that i still have to create similar struct containing object with dynamic type (2) since i am expecting the object can be passed directly to the C++ code again in the WCF client side, i need to perform "another" mapping to the C++ struct again which i am trying to avoid. . any suggestions? thank you

Comment: @BloodroseWu I think that actually makes a very good case of **exactly why** you should be using a DTO; it is not reasonable for WCF to worry about the internals of your COM code, and the API currently is far too vague to be useful to callers, IMO.

Comment: thanks marc... still, i need your suggestion. so basically what i am doing is this. i have an old system, **C++ client --> DCOM Server**; now i have to change it to **C++ Client-->.NET Component(server as a COM Svr + a WCF Client)-->WCF Service-->DCOM Server**.  so i need to define based on the existing DCOM Server interfaces to generate my WCF interfaces (as as the Struct as Data Contract). I am trying to define a contract definitions can be passed from **C++->C#-->WCF-->DCOM** boundary and avoid too much mapping in between.. So far, this 'VARIANT' is a headache for me.